# Visual Basic 2010 Space in File for Process.Star

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to understund how to work with multiple spaces in file location but i still have an issue.

```
Process.Start(%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX\XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX.appref-ms)
```

And I tried multiple solutions but none of them helped me.

Can some one help Me with this?

Thanks

Comment: A file path is a string, and string literals need to be enclosed in double quotations. Use `Process.Start("The\path\to\the\file")`. Also, note that this applies to any string literal and not exclusive to `Process.Start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file path is simply a string. In VB.NET, string literals need to be enclosed in double quotations `""`. In other words, in order to have a string hardcoded anywhere into your code, it must be enclosed in double quotations *and that's not exclusive to `Process.Start()`, it applies to any string literal, and it doesn't matter whether the string contains a space or not*.

So, in order to pass a file path to `Process.Start()`, you can either directly call:

```
Process.Start("The\path\to\your\file")
'Process.Start(The\path\to\your\file)   ' Wrong! Won't compile.
```

..or, you can do this:

```
Dim filePath As String = "The\path\to\your\file"
Process.Start(filePath)
```

That said, please note that `Process.Start("%userprofile%\...")` will not work because VB.NET doesn't convert `%userprofile%` to the actual path to the current user directory. In order to do that, you need to use [`Environment.GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) with the appropriate [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) enum.

Something like the following should work:

```
Dim userDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(userDir, "AppData\Roaming\...")
Process.Start(filePath)
```

Or you can get the `%AppData%` path (I.E., `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming`) directly using:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Hope that helps.